# Provide data for multiple ng-contents, from an ngTemplate

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template, ng-template, ng-content

I'm trying to project data to several ng-contents, but through an ng-template.
something like this:

**child.component.ts**

```
<ng-content select="[first]"></ng-content>

<h3>seperator</h3>

<ng-content select="[second]"></ng-content>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
<child>
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
</child>

<ng-template #template>
    <h3 first> First </h3>
    <h3 second> Second </h3>
</ng-template>
```

The problem is it doesn't work.
If I don't use the "select" attribute it does work, but doesn't place the divs in the correct places.

I have tried using `ContentChildren` and adding the `TemplateRef` manually in the child-component but it still won't render the divs in the correct places.

Stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdqmkl?file=src/app/child.component.ts

Comment: Any reason you can't have two templates? One for 'first' and another for 'second"? Then do something like: `<child>
    <ng-container first [ngTemplateOutlet]="firstTemplate"></ng-container>
</child>`

Comment: This template acts as a 'common' for many children, who each places the selectors in different places. I rather have a single template, inject it to all the different children and let each one set the styles and locations of the injected contents.